# Use Cauchy Criterion to prove that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \sin x $does not exist

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Use Cauchy Criterion to prove that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \sin x$ does not exist, 
Could anyone give me a hint please?

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0}\sin(x)=0$.  So, it will be a challenge to use Cauchy to show otherwise.

Comment: Sooo Sorry, I have corrected the question. :)))

Comment: For all $B>0$, we choose $x=n\pi>B$ and $y=n\pi+\pi/2$.  Then, 

$$|\sin(x)-\sin(y)|=1$$